# Trying to derive Polchinski's equation $(2.2.11)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I'm having trouble to derive Polchinski's equation $(2.2.11)$ which is an example of product of normal ordered product of $\partial X^\mu$. Precisely, Polchinski defines the product of normal ordered operators $:\mathcal{F}:$ and $:\mathcal{G}:$ (which are functionals of the  fields $X$) in the following way,

$$:\mathcal{F}: :\mathcal{G}: \ =\  :\mathcal{F}\mathcal{G}: + \  \text{cross contractions}, \tag1$$

cf. eq. $(2.2.9)$, or as the formula given by $(2.2.10)$

$$:\mathcal{F}::\mathcal{G}: = \exp \left( -\frac{\alpha'}{2} \int d^2z_1 d^2z_2 \ln |z_1 - z_2|^2  \frac{\delta}{\delta X^\mu_F(z_1)}  \frac{\delta}{\delta X_{G\mu}(z_2)}   \right):\mathcal{F}\mathcal{G}: \tag2$$

Polchinski's first example is with $:\partial X_\mu \partial X^\mu(z)::\partial' X_\nu \partial' X^\nu(z'):$. If I use the "imprecise" first definition, I get the following:

We have that $\mathcal{F} = \partial X^0 \partial X_0 (z) + \cdots + \partial X^{D-1} \partial X_{D-1}(z) $ and that $\mathcal{G} = \partial' X^0 \partial' X_0 (z') + \cdots + \partial' X^{D-1} \partial' X_{D-1}(z')$

We can only make contractions between terms with same greek index. For each index, there are $4$ ways to perform a pair and $2$ ways to perform two pairs such that the sum of cross-contractions is given by

$$-4 \cdot \dfrac{\alpha'}{2} \partial \partial' \ln |z-z'|^2 \partial X^\mu(z) \partial' X_\mu (z') + 2 \eta^\mu_\mu \cdot  \left( \dfrac{\alpha'}{2} \partial \partial' \ln |z-z'|^2 \right)^2. \tag4$$

The problem is that the first term right above differs from the RHS of $(2.2.11)$ by a normal ordering, and I can't figure out where is my mistake.
Even if I use the equation

$$:\partial X^\mu(z)\partial' X_\mu(z'): =\partial X^\mu(z)\partial' X_\mu(z') - \dfrac{\alpha'}{2} \eta^\mu _\mu \partial \partial' \ln|z-z'|^2 \tag5$$

the terms do not match.

Besides that, I cannot find a way to get the equation by formula $(2)$, because I get divergent terms of the type $\ln |z-z|^2$. I will appreciate any help with this problem

Edit: here equation $(5)$ was obtained using the definition or normal ordering given in $(2.2.7)$ by Polchinski. It does not make sense to me that the terms multiplying the single pairs of $ln|z|^2$ have to be normal ordered since his formula tells you exactly the opposite.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Virasoro TT OPE (2.2.11) in Polchinski's book](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59810/2451)

Comment: In that question, OP already knows why the first equality $(2.2.11)$ has that specific form.